# Testing Contracts

Tags: wasm, exchange, unit-tests

There used to be a directory wasm_tests in the eos/tests directory which contained several c++ files that unit tested contracts. https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/dawn-v3.0.0/tests/wasm_tests . This directory has since been removed.

Is there already in existence a good way to test standard currency, exchange, system, and skeleton multisig contracts? How is it best to go about testing them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [eosfactory](http://eosfactory.io/sphinx/build/html/)

Here is a simple tutorial you can follow:
https://medium.com/coinmonks/your-first-eos-dapp-using-eosfactory-aa0394df95d9

Comment: Here is introduction blog post https://steemit.com/eos/@tokenika/introducing-eosfactory-v1-1-the-go-to-ide-for-eos-smart-contract-testing

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for this:
https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/master/unittests

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://github.com/LimeChain/eoslime
There is an example how to test eosio.token and you could test any custom contract this way.
There is short documentation in the readme and the example is here: https://docs.eoslime.limechain.tech/examples

Keep in mind that you need to change the eoslime require.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a tutorial on how to write unit tests for EOSIO (EOS, Telos & Worbli) smart contracts with **JavaScript** which you might find really helpful. You can check it [here](https://medium.com/infinitexlabs/unit-test-eos-smart-contracts-with-javascript-20ea8840b5bc). We're using [infeos](https://medium.com/infinitexlabs/infeos-the-eosio-universe-in-your-hands-22d928ec6ee3) - a javascript & npm framework for developing, deploying and testing EOSIO dApps